# how to read directory (files are n in number) in command prompt using arguments

Tags: python, pandas, glob, argv, sys

currently, I am using arguments while passing the filenames in the code.

usage :

```
!python C:/Users/sindhus/Desktop/Fio/fio_mergefiles.py 1.log 2.log 3.log .......n output.csv
```

The code I am using is as below. The "readers" in the below code I am using it to pass for other function.

```
debug = False
argv = ['']+['f%02d'%n for n in range(1, n)]+[''] if debug else argv
out  = stdout if debug else open(argv[-1], 'w')

readers = [reader(open(f), n) for n, f in enumerate(argv[1:-1])]
N = len(readers) 
print('Interval',*('IOPS%02d'%(n+1) for n in range(N)), sep=',', file=out)

# initialize for the loop
t0 = ""

# the loop
for t,iops,extra1,extra2,n in merge(*readers, key=lambda x:int(x[0])):
    if t != t0:
        if t0: print(t0, *iops_l, sep=',', file=out)
        t0 = t
        iops_l = ['····' if debug else '']*N
    iops_l[n] = '%4s'%iops if debug else iops
```

now I am planning to keep all the input files in the folder and I want to parse only the directory name and the output_file path. I tried using path list and glob dint help much.

what I want is

```
!python C:/Users/sindhus/Desktop/Fio/fio_mergefiles.py C:/Users/data/ C:/Users/output/output.csv
```

I have edited my code as most of them wanted what the "readers" parameter was returning.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Comment: what will your reader return, that you wish to place in a list?

Comment: " I tried using path list and glob dint help much." What did you try exactly?

Comment: Anyway, you can use `Path(dirname).glob("*.csv")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is changed as below

```
cmd_folder_input_iops = Path(sys.argv[1])
glob_folder_iops = cmd_folder_input_iops.glob('*')
readers = [reader(open(f), n) for n, f in enumerate(glob_folder_iops)]
N=len(readers)
out_iops  = stdout if debug else open(argv[2], 'w')

# header is "Interval,IOPS01,IOPS02,...,IOPSnn" modify as you like
print('Interval',*('IOPS%02d'%(n+1) for n in range(N)), sep=',', file=out_iops)

# initialize for the loop
t0 = ""

# the loop
for t,iops,extra1,extra2,n in merge(*readers, key=lambda x:int(x[0])):

    if t != t0:
       if t0: print(t0, *iops_l, sep=',', file=out_iops)
       t0 = t
       iops_l = ['····' if debug else '']*N
    
   iops_l[n] = '%4s'%iops if debug else iops

# the last record to output
print(t0, *iops_l, sep=',', file=out_iops)`
```

Regards,
Sindhu

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `os.listdir` function:

```
import os

folder_path = "your/folder/path"

for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    with open(os.path.join(folder_path, filename), "r") as fp:
        # ...
```

Comment: if I use the above code then in readers = I have argv[1:-1] .. What should be changed there...